# dplyr groupby percentage and renaming the column

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I want to group by my dataframe based on promotion offered and calculate the percentage.  The data frame is of following format

```
Promotion name             days rented
nan                        577
first month half off       88
nan                        22
second month free          55
nan                        60
first month half off       20
```

if my dataframe is called df.  how would i group by promotion name and calculate the percentage of days and rename that column.  So, my first column would be "# of rentals less than 1 month".  In R, i would say:

```
df %>% group_by(`Promotion Name`) %>% 
summarise("# Rentals < 1 month" = sum(`Days rented` <= 30)/length(`Days rented`)
```

Can someone please help in python.  I tried the following:

I want the format to be:

```
Promotion Name         # rentals < 1 month    # rentals < 2 month   # rentals < 3 months
None                   0.0023                 0.005                0.28
First month half off   0.78                   0.22                 0.76
2nd month free         0.44     etc
```

I tried

```
rented_df.groupby('Promotion Name').sum()
```

But this is not giving me what i want as i want to sum days < 30 and calculate the length and finally rename the column.  Thanks.

Comment: if you are going to vote me down, why not try helping first?

Comment: SO is not a site for code translation service. I guess this is why you got downvote. The other reason you might get the downvote is because you did not provide a reproducible example of the `cube` dataframe. Why don't you provide the dataset and post the python code you have tried so far?

Comment: is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = rented_df.groupby('Promotion name')['days rented']
              .apply(lambda x: x[x<=30].sum()/len(x)).reset_index(name='# Rentals < 1 month')
print (df)
         Promotion name  # Rentals < 1 month
1  first month half off            10.000000
2     second month free             0.000000
```

But groupby by default remove `NaN`s, so if need them first replace `NaN` to some string which is no in column before by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
rented_df['Promotion name'] = rented_df['Promotion name'].fillna('NANS strings')
df = rented_df.groupby('Promotion name')['days rented']
              .apply(lambda x: x[x<=30].sum()/len(x)).reset_index(name='# Rentals < 1 month')
print (df)
         Promotion name  # Rentals < 1 month
0          NANS strings             7.333333
1  first month half off            10.000000
2     second month free             0.000000
```

For separate column need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
rented_df['Promotion name'] = rented_df['Promotion name'].fillna('NANS strings')
rented_df['# Rentals < 1 month'] = rented_df.groupby('Promotion name')['days rented']
                                            .transform(lambda x: x[x<=30].sum()/len(x))
print (rented_df)
         Promotion name  days rented  # Rentals < 1 month
0          NANS strings          577             7.333333
1  first month half off           88            10.000000
2          NANS strings           22             7.333333
3     second month free           55             0.000000
4          NANS strings           60             7.333333
5  first month half off           20            10.000000
```

EDIT:

```
rented_df['Promotion name'] = rented_df['Promotion name'].fillna('NANS strings')
g = rented_df.groupby('Promotion name')['days rented']
s1 = g.apply(lambda x: x[x<=30].sum()/len(x)).rename('# Rentals < 1 month')
s2 = g.apply(lambda x: x[x<=60].sum()/len(x)).rename('# Rentals < 2 month')
s3 = g.apply(lambda x: x[x<=90].sum()/len(x)).rename('# Rentals < 3 month')
df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
         Promotion name  # Rentals < 1 month  # Rentals < 2 month  \
0          NANS strings             7.333333            27.333333   
1  first month half off            10.000000            10.000000   
2     second month free             0.000000            55.000000   

   # Rentals < 3 month  
0            27.333333  
1            54.000000  
2            55.000000
```

Comment: thanks.  Is there anyway to rename the column in one shot? and also, where do i learn this stuff?  so that i don't ask simple questions anymore

Comment: I rename column now, see last edit. and for learning stuff are best [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) I think and code, code and code. Mainly it need some time and to be patient. good luck!

Comment: renaming is by parameter `name` in `reset_index` function

Comment: btw, if i wanted to calculate seperate columns for x[x<=60] as well, can this be done in one shot?  or do i need to create seperate groupby and write out this condition?   thanks

Comment: i think your last edit overwrites the rented_df dataframe which is not grouped by.

Comment: hmmm, this is 2 different solution with `apply` - data are aggregated or by `transform` - data are not aggregate but create new column of original dataframe. So need choose first or second, not together.

Comment: Hmmm, and what are conditions? `<=60, 90, 120` ?

Comment: 30,60 and 90.  4 columns in total including "promotion name" in first column

Comment: im confused.  In R, i could say...
df %>% group_by('Promotion Name') %>% summarize('# of rentals less than 1 month' = sum('Days rented' <= 30)/ length('Days rented'),
"# Rentals < 2 months" = sum(`Days rented` <= 60)/length(`Days rented`),
"# Rentals < 3 months" = sum(`Days rented` <= 90)/length(`Days rented`)) %>% View

when i tried your method, for <= 60, im getting large numbers and not percentages which is weird.

Comment: thanks.  but for some reason, my  answer doesn't match what i get in R at all.

Comment: Hmmm, hard find problem without real data. what is difference?

Comment: i will post some data in few hours.  sorry have a meeting all day today based on my results.  thanks a bunch.  I will try to make it simple and include a 10 row 4 column dataset